# Render a partial in a <div> on clicking a link tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i render a partial inside a  tag on the clicking of a href tag.

```
<a href = "#" class= "addWidget" value = "Add Widget">add</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".addWidget").click(function(){
  <%= render :partial => 'form'%>
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you specify which server side language are you using? It seems like ASP.NET MVC but I'm not sure

Comment: <%= render :partial => 'form'%>  => what is Html output ??

Comment: @Kiranu :-
Its rails and i have got my solution. Nywaz Thanks.

Comment: @volkan er :- 
the html output is a form. Nywaz I have got my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to embed the partial content, you could simply:

```
$('.addWidget').click(function(){
    $(this).append("<%= render :partial => 'form'%>");
});
```

Note that the html of your <%= render ...%> code needs to be quoted in the Javascript - here I've done so with double quotes, but whether double or single, be sure to escape them in the rendering of the partial.

Comment: where was this jquery that worked located?  I didn't think you could render a partial on client side jquery...